# Need for speed underground 1 shows in taskbar then dissappears

Tags: laptop, gaming

So I got need for speed underground 1 today and it runs on my desktop without a hitch but it refuses to work on my laptop. All it does is it shows in the taskbar for 5 secs then disappears as if I never clicked on the game.
(P.S running the game on Win 10)

Comment: If that happens, the game crashes. See if there are any logs. Also reinstall the game, check for compatibility settings etc. Also it may not run on windows 10.

Comment: @LPChip Both my desktop and laptop run on Windows 10.And I've tried compatibility on my laptop but it still crashes.

Comment: Did you completely uninstalled, rebooted, reinstalled? That may fix a missing dependency.

Comment: @LPChip So I reinstalled the game on my laptop and it still crashed. I also played the game on my school's computers (they also have win 10) and they worked perfectly there. Maybe it doesn't run on laptops?